# Visual Studio C++ change programmatically font of controls

Tags: fonts, c++-cli, label

I've searched on the internet, but i couldn't find how to pro grammatically change the font of a label that I created on startup... I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
mylabel->Font->Size = 11;
```

Build log: error C2039: 'set' : is not a member of 'System::Drawing::Font::Size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Font::Size property only has a getter, not a setter, so your code does not compile.  Always mention error messages when you ask a question.

The alternative is to simply create a new Font object, like this:

```
  mylabel->Font = gcnew System::Drawing::Font(mylabel->Font->FontFamily, 11);
```